# Inserting Values Into Multidimensional Array, But Only Got 1 Inserted

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array :

```
$order_list = array ( array ("tangible", 1, 8, 1, 19000),
                      array ("tangible", 6, 2, 10, NULL),
                      array ("tangible", 1, 17, 1, 28000));
```

and I want to have this as an output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array       //$order_list[1]
        (
            [0] => 8   //$order_list[2]
            [1] => 17  //$order_list[2]
        )

    [6] => Array       //$order_list[1]
        (
            [0] => 2   //$order_list[2]
        )

)
```

here's my code :

```
$order_array = array ();

foreach ($order_list as $value) {

    $vendor_id = $value[1];
    $product_id = array($value[2]);
    $order_array[$vendor_id] = $product_id;

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($order_array);
```

this only produce :

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )
```

how to have this :

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 17 //second value inserted into same array
        )
```

thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to turn the other value as another separate array. Just push them normally, one used as the key (in this case `$vendor_id`), then another as another normal value pushed (in this case the `$product_id` alone not as `array($value[2])`):

```
foreach ($order_list as $value) {

    $vendor_id = $value[1];
    $product_id = $value[2]; // just that single element, no need to assign it into another container
    $order_array[$vendor_id][] = $product_id;
    // use as key   ^        ^ then just push it

}
```

By doing this:

```
$order_array[$vendor_id] = $product_id;
```

This will overwrite that key pair value instead of continually pushing elements inside of it.

Comment: @RobertHanson sure glad this helped